# Blazor UriHelper.NavigateTo is calling the page twice

Tags: blazor

I created a new Blazor Server Side Application in Preview 8.  When I call the UriHelper.NavigateTo to go to the counter page from the Index.razor page, the counter page is called twice.

In the Index.razor page I have this code:

```
@code{

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        UriHelper.NavigateTo("/counter");
    }

}
```

Then in the counter page I added the following code with a breakpoint in it:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{

}
```

My expectation is to call the counter page only one time when the NavigateTo calls the counter route in the Index.razor

Comment: MS doc said, If the OnInitialized{Async} lifecycle method for initializing the component is present, the method is executed twice. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#stateful-reconnection-after-prerendering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update due to a comment by dani herrera:

The life cycle method OnInitializedAsync is called twice, but the counter @page component is called once only.
This behavior is by design. The first time OnInitializedAsync is executed is when server-side Blazor app is being pre-rendering, during which time, JSInterop is not available, and thus calling `UriHelper.NavigateTo("/counter");` triggers an error. The following code snippet describe how Blazor currently treats such cases:

```
protected override void NavigateToCore(string uri, bool forceLoad)
        {
            Log.RequestingNavigation(_logger, uri, forceLoad);

            if (_jsRuntime == null)
            {
                var absoluteUriString = ToAbsoluteUri(uri).ToString();
                throw new NavigationException(absoluteUriString);
            }

            _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>(Interop.NavigateTo, uri, forceLoad);
        }
```

[See more here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/3148acfb105a16aa6c535d00eb0e50ec03992f3f/src/Components/Server/src/Circuits/RemoteNavigationManager.cs). As you may realize, the counter @page component is not called, and an exception is raised.

After pre-rendering has completed, client-side SignalR establishes a connection to the server, and your app is rendered. This time (second time the method OnInitializedAsync is called) `UriHelper.NavigateTo("/counter");` is properly executed, and we are happily navigated to the counter page  (first time)

You may use the method OnAfterRender as a workaround, and you should verify whether a connection with the server has already been established by SignalR; that is the pre-rendering process has completed.

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@inject IComponentContext ComponentContext
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<p>Navigate to the counter component.</p>

@code{

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (!ComponentContext.IsConnected) return;

         UriHelper.NavigateTo("/counter");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Issac:  You are right when I added it in the OnAfterRender the component is called just once.  The only thing is that I dont understand the cause if this is a bug or this is the normal behavior.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Issac, I guess `OnAfterRender` is not a good option because at that point all page code has already been executed, to late for some scenarios (like redirect to login page for non login users). Also, your explanation about execute `OnInitializedAsync` looks weird, this only happens on pre-rendering. See my post for details.

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is because the pre-render feature. Notice that, when you are on `counter page` (loaded for twice), if you click on `Home`, only one execution is fired:

[image]

#### Summarizing:

When pre-render is enabled (by default), the prerended page's `OnInitializedAsync`  is called for twice [by design](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13607#issuecomment-527548256). For this reason, your redirect statement is executed for twice.

To test is I wrote this code on index `OnInitializedAsync`:

```
@page "/"
@inject IUriHelper UriHelper

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@code{

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("_*   ");
        System.Console.WriteLine("_**************************");
        System.Console.WriteLine("_***** Pre render ******");
        System.Console.WriteLine("_**************************");
        System.Console.WriteLine("_   ");
        return;
    }
}
```

And I call the page using pre-render and from the app (without prerender). Noticed that when I force reload (prerended) the `OnInitializedAsync` is executed for twice:

[image]

Learn more about [render modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#integrate-components-into-razor-pages-and-mvc-apps).

Comment: what's the matter with the graphics. It makes navigation in this thread almost impossible. Can't you do something about it ?

Comment: What do you mean with "This behavior will change on preview9"? What is the new behaviour?

Comment: @Benni , no changes at end. Thanks, answer fixed.